# Angular Controller as ES6 Class: "[ng:areq] Argument ***Controller is not a function, got undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, angular-controller

Attempting to build a basic Angular todo application w/ES6.  As far as I can tell, the controller should be registering, but I continue to get the title error when routed to the associated state.

*App.js referenced in index is the Babel transpiled Webpack output

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
  </head>
  <body ng-app="todoApp">
    <script src="../dist/app.js"></script>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import ngStorage from 'angular-storage';
import ngMaterial from 'angular-material';
import ngAnimate from 'angular-animate';
import ngAria from 'angular-aria';

import config from './config/config'

(() => {
  const ngModule = angular.module('todoApp', [uiRouter, ngStorage, ngAnimate, ngAria, ngMaterial]);
  config(ngModule);
})();
```

**config.js**

```
import httpAuthInterceptor from './interceptors/httpAuthInterceptor';
import constants from './constants';

import login from '../login/index';
import todos from '../todos/index';
import todo from '../todos/todo/index';
import services from '../services/index';

export default ngModule => {
  httpAuthInterceptor(ngModule);
  services(ngModule);

  ngModule.constant('CONSTANTS', constants);

  ngModule.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController as vm'
      })
      .state('todos', {
        url: '/todos',
        templateUrl: 'app/todos/todos.html',
        controller: 'todosController as vm'
      });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpAuthInterceptor');

    login(ngModule);
    todos(ngModule);
    todo(ngModule);
  });
}
```

**login/index.js**

```
import controller from "./login.controller";
import service from "./login.service";

export default ngModule => {
  controller(ngModule);
  service(ngModule);
};
```

**login/login.controller.js**

```
export default ngModule => {
  let controllerName = 'loginController';

  class loginController {
    constructor(loginService) {
      this.loginService = loginService;
      this.username;
      this.password;
    }
  }

  ngModule.controller(controllerName, loginController);
};
```

More confusing to me is that the service below loads fine:

**services/index.js**

```
import session from "./session.service";

export default ngModule => {
  session(ngModule);
};
```

**services/session.service.js**

```
export default ngModule => {
  let providerName = 'sessionService';

  class sessionService {
    constructor(store, CONSTANTS) {
      this.CONSTANTS = CONSTANTS;
      this.store = store;

      this.currentSessionToken;

      this.init();
    }

    init() {
      this.currentSessionToken = this.retrieveSession();
      console.log(this.currentSessionToken)
    }

    storeSession (token) {
      this.store.set(this.CONSTANTS.JWT_TOKEN_KEY, token);
      this.currentSessionToken = token;
    }

    retrieveSession() {
      return this.store.get(this.CONSTANTS.JWT_TOKEN_KEY);
    }

    isAuthenticated() {
      let token = this.retrieveSession();
      if(token) {
        let tokenParams = _parseJwt(token);
        return Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) <= tokenParams.exp;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  ngModule.service(providerName, sessionService);

  let _parseJwt = function(token) {
    let base64Data = token.split('.')[1];
    let base64 = base64Data.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
    return JSON.parse(this.$window.atob(base64));
  }.bind(sessionService);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message? Is it your login or todo controller that is triggering the error?

Comment: angular.js:13920 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'todosController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=todosController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at...

Comment: Either login or todos controller errors when switching to the respective state.

Comment: So what does your `todosController` look like?

Comment: Same as login, with an empty constructor.

Comment: You need to eliminate potential issues here. Either provide your `todosController` implementation or remove the `todos` state from your app to make sure that's not a problem

Comment: Removing the todos state, todos/todo import statements, and function calls in config results in no change to the error.

Comment: Cool, thanks for trying that out. Pretty sure I've got the answer for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move these three calls

```
login(ngModule);
todos(ngModule);
todo(ngModule);
```

**outside** the `config` function; they don't belong in there at all.

```
// in config.js

export default ngModule => {
  httpAuthInterceptor(ngModule);
  services(ngModule);
  login(ngModule);
  todos(ngModule);
  todo(ngModule);

  ngModule.constant('CONSTANTS', constants);

  ngModule.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) => {
    // etc
```

Comment: That was it.  The only reason the service was working was because I had ran that function before the config.  Thanks much, that would have turned into a giant rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

Try add your controller.js in index.html

```
<script src="../dist/login/login.controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oops, left that part out.  App.js in dist/ is the transpiled Webpack output.